# How to append a list with a single string to a list?

Tags: python, list

I was wondering how I would be able to append a list to a list?

```
x = []
x.append(list(('H4','H3')))
print x # [['H4', 'H3']]

x.append(list('H4'))
print x # [['H4', 'H3'], ['H','4']]
```

I was wondering how I could get `[['H4', 'H3'], ['H4']]` instead of `[['H4', 'H3'], ['H','4']]`. I scoured the web and I only saw `x.extend` which isn't really what I wanted :\

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[]` instead of `list`:

```
x.append(['H4'])
```

The `list` function (which constructs a new list) takes an iterable in parameter and adds every element of the iterable in the list. BUT, strings are iterable in Python, so each element (characters here) are added as elements in the list. Using `[]` shortcut avoid that.

[From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list):

> `list([iterable])`
>
> Return a list whose items are the same and in the same order as iterable‘s items. iterable may be either a sequence, a container that supports iteration, or an iterator object. If iterable is already a list, a copy is made and returned, similar to iterable[:]. **For instance, `list('abc')` returns `['a', 'b', 'c']`** and list( (1, 2, 3) ) returns [1, 2, 3]. If no argument is given, returns a new empty list, [].